# Find out when text is over contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to find out, when my text goes over the content editable div.

```
I dont want to have a scroll or anything, just as it is.
```

What I want is to block (not hiding with overflow, blocking!!) any text which goes below the div.

Here is my JSFiddle with my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/N4tTp/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe u could use dotdotdot jquery plugin..but that is something related to multiline ellipsis..hope it helps..

Comment: or limit the number of characters like this http://jsfiddle.net/A69tk/46/

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div.block{margin:20px;width:400px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;}
 //defined some style just for demonstration
</style>
<body>
    <div  class="block" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="ManageOverflow(event)">
    Block Content
    </div>  
</body>
<script>
function ManageOverflow(event){
    if(event.target.scrollHeight > event.target.clientHeight){
        //your action here
    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's are saying, you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but unfortunately, this will only work with one line (not multi lines)

### [example](http://jsfiddle.net/N4tTp/3/)

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

If you want multi-lines, you won't get an ellipsis

```
overflow: hidden;
```

### [multiline example without ellipsis](http://jsfiddle.net/N4tTp/5/)

Comment: well, i need multiline .. what would be a solution approahc for that?

Comment: @PlicPl I updated my answer with multiline. If you want an ellipsis to show on multiline, you'll need to use JavaScript to figure out if the text will overflow, and then append an ellipsis

Comment: What is the reason for the div being `contenteditable`? Is a user going to be typing in the box?

Comment: yes, its a box where users can type some text in which should be blocked on the bottom exactly like here http://jsfiddle.net/37Jnn/45/

Comment: its for textareas, and contenteditable divs havent those methods

Comment: u could rather use a textarea and edit its css to look like contenteditable div..